# Redis Stream NOMKSTREAM

Tags: redis, redis-streams

What is this `NOMKSTREAM` in redis stream?
I went through the documentation. Too bad they do not even provide simple description about it.

https://redis.io/commands/xadd

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if the stream key doesn't exist, `XADD` will create the stream automatically. However, if NOMKSTREAM is specified, `XADD` will return a NULL reply in this case.

Comment: NOMKSTREAM stands for?

Comment: do NOt MaKe a STREAM automatically.

Comment: Not only it will return a NULL reply, but the stream will not be created at all.

Answer (score 0):

The "simple" description is right at the beginning of [`XADD`'s doc page](https://redis.io/commands/xadd):

> The creation of stream's key can be disabled with the NOMKSTREAM option.

Please feel free to improve the docs by contributing to https://github.com/redis/redis-doc

Comment: My question was related to full form of NOMKSTREAM